# Capture ellipsis / three dots within a function; ignoring explicitly mentioned arguments

Tags: r, rlang

I would like to collect the names of additional arguments on a function (ellipsis / three dots).

The following example works as expected

```
CollectDots <- function(...) {
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots(A, B, C)
# "A" "B" "C"
```

However, if the function contains one or more parameters (either with/without default value), the output is not as expected.

```
CollectDots1 <- function(Var1 = NA, ...) {
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots1(A, B, C) # 1 explicit parameter, returning only B and C
# "B" "C"

CollectDots2 <- function(Var1 = NA, Var2, ...) {
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots2(A, B, C) # 2 explicit parameters, returning C
# "C"
```

Further, if `var1 = 10`, why the following function does not print 10 and throws an error

```
CollectDots3 <- function(Var1 = 10, Var2, ...) {
  print(Var1)
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots3(A, B, C)
# Error: object 'A' not found
```

How to only collect the names of additional arguments provided to the function (...), excluding parameters explicitly mentioned in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a function, for example: `function(Var1 = NA, ...)`, you're saying that the function takes one named argument `Var1` and if nothing is present for that argument (either named *or in that position*), use `NA`.  In the `CollectDots1()` function, you get only "B" and "C" because it assumes you want to specify `Var1=A`.  If you put the dots first, before the named arguments, you get what you expect.

```r
CollectDots1 <- function(..., Var1 = NA) {
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}

CollectDots1(A, B, C)
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

In `CollectDots3()` below, the function assumes your specifying `Var1=A` and `Var2=B`.  Since you're then trying to print `A` without `A` being defined, the error is generated.

```r
CollectDots3 <- function(Var1 = 10, Var2, ...) {
  print(Var1)
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots3(A, B, C)
```

Again, putting the three dots first will give you what you expect:

```r
CollectDots3 <- function(..., Var1 = 10, Var2) {
  print(Var1)
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots3(A, B, C)
#> [1] 10
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Note, the above only works because you're not calling `Var2` which has no default and is not defined in the call to the function.  If your function tried to access `Var2` without it being named, then you would get an error:

```r
CollectDots3 <- function(..., Var1 = 10, Var2) {
  print(Var1)
  cat(Var2)
  as.character(rlang::ensyms(...))
}
CollectDots3(A, B, C)
#> [1] 10
#> Error in CollectDots3(A, B, C): argument "Var2" is missing, with no default
```

Finally, there is one implication of doing things this way (i.e., putting the three dots first) -- it is that you must always explicitly name all of the named arguments to the function when you call it.  For example, if you wanted to use `Var1=20`, you would have to say `CollectDots3(Var1=20)`

Comment: Clearly explained. Thanks.. However, this way, I can not use the pipe operator  `%>%` directly. I have to tell e.g. `DF %>% CollectDots3(Var1 = ., Var 2 = 10)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in base R using `match.call`

```r
CollectDots1 <- function(Var1 = NA, ...) {
  mc <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  sapply(mc, as.character) |> unname()
}

CollectDots1(A, B, C)
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: This looks like a more robust approach than @Dave's  answer.

Comment: Doesn't this still produce the same problem because it is still seeing `A` as assigned value to the argument `Var1`?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong you're right - I misunderstood the question. I think this just makes it easier though - see my update.

Comment: @AllanCameron - that makes sense.  I think that solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative which may not exactly meet your needs. Put this inside your function

```
elist <- list(...)
dotNames <- names(elist)
```